# Deploying shiny R app to shinyapps.io gives SQL connectivity error for the connection string

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Hi i am using this connection string to deploy to shinyapps.io but it never connects

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQLServer",
                      Server = "server",
                      Database = "db",
                      UID ="user",
                      PWD="pass",
                      Port = 1433)
```

It gives this error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [RStudio][SqlServer] Failed to locate Server/Instance Specified. 
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
```

Comment: Probably your server is not reachable from the Internet.

Comment: The server is always connected through internet as it resides on AWS, it connects fine locally.I am sure something is wrong with the connection string

Comment: Did you check if you are connecting to the right host? You did not specify the host in the database connection.
Also make sure that your AWS instance is configured to allow remote connections. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/getting-started-with-r-on-amazon-web-services/

Comment: AWS is allowed is configured to allow remote connections, I have got the Host name , what would be the connection string then?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple problems here.

Firstly, you may need to whiteslist shinyapps.io's IP addresses, the full list is available [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217592507-How-do-I-give-my-application-on-shinyapps-io-access-to-my-remote-database-). If your database is hosted on Azure or AWS, you can easily do it there, or ask your corporate admin to help.

Secondly, you'll need to explicitly specify which drivers shinyapps.io should use to access your database. Normally, when you connect to your database locally from R, you specify `Driver = "SQL Server"`.

However, for shinyapps.io it needs to be `Driver = "FreeTDS"`.

You'll need to set up a function that recognises if the app is being run locally or not, and uses a relevant driver. in case of the latter you'll also need to specify a port and a TDS version, like this:

```
# Check if the app is being run locally or on the server
is_local <- Sys.getenv("SHINY_PORT") == ""

# A function to connect to the SQL database
dbConnector <- function(server, database, uid, pwd, local = TRUE, port = 1433, tds_version = 7.4) {
  
  # Local connect
  if (local) {
    DBI::dbConnect(
      odbc::odbc(), 
      Driver   = "SQL Server", 
      Server   = server,
      Database = database,
      UID      = uid,
      PWD      = pwd
    )
  } else {
    # Remote connect
    DBI::dbConnect(
      odbc::odbc(), 
      Driver      = "FreeTDS", 
      Server      = server,
      Database    = database,
      UID         = uid,
      PWD         = pwd,
      Port        = port,
      TDS_Version = tds_version
    )
  }
}

# Connect to the SQL database
con <- dbConnector(server, database, uid, pwd, is_local)
```